# Codeigniter: dropdown value stays after refreshing

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is the code in view:

```
echo "<p>Salutation: ";
    $salutationOptions = array(
                  ''    => '',
                  'Dr'  => 'Dr',
                  'Mr'  => 'Mr',
                  'Ms'  => 'Ms',
                  'Mdm' => 'Mdm',
                );
    echo form_dropdown('salutation', $salutationOptions, '', 'required="required"');
    echo "</p>";
```

I would like to know if i am able to repopulate the dropdown if the validation fails. As the output for now would be blank, if the validation fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter is the one that defines the default value. Use it :)

```
form_dropdown('salutation', $salutationOptions, set_value('salutation', 'Dr'), 'required="required"');
```

More details here : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html